# Append column to a dataframe using list comprehension format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, list-comprehension

I would like to append a **column of zeros** to a dataframe if the column in question is not already inside the dataframe.

If the dataframe looks like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,0], 'c':[1,1,1]})

----------------------------------------------
    a   c
0   0   1
1   1   1
2   0   1
```

And the complete list of **column names** that the dataframe should have are:

```py
col_names = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I would like the output to look like this after applying the **list comprehension** to the df:

```py
    a    b    c
0   0    0    1
1   1    0    1
2   0    0    1
```

This is the complete code I have so far:

```py
col_names = ['a','b','c']

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,0], 'c':[1,1,1]})

# This is what I would like to convert into a list comprehension (one line) format if possible
for col in col_names:
    if col not in df.columns:
        df[col] = 0

# Re-order the columns into the correct order        
df = df[col_names]

print(df)
```

Comment: Is there such a thing as a column comprehension ?? :)

Comment: It's not really clear what you're looking for. It seems like you just want to add missing columns in a "more elegant" way than a plain `for` loop?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list comprehension would produce a list. You don't want a list, you want to add columns to your dataframe. **List comprehensions should not be used for side effects, ever.**

You can however, produce the columns you want to add as a list and use advanced indexing to assign all the columns at the same time:

```py
df[[col for col in col_names if col not in df.columns]] = 0
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. But not sure why you suggest this should not be done ??

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the above. I was only warning that trying to do an assignment inside a comprehension is an anti-pattern, which is what it originally sounded like you were asking for.